# How can I encode the current document as a QR code with pst-barcode?

Tags: macros, pstricks, verbatim, expansion, pst-barcode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
  \psbarcode{\input{\jobname.tex}}{}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried placing `\expandafter`s before and after `\psbarcode`, but no juice.
It can handle control sequences just fine, but it will expand them.
How can I get it to not expand its argument at all (save, of course, `\input`) and take it verbatim?

The encoding of this particular document is

[image]

Comment: This can’t really work because `\input` already makes a test for `{` to decide between the TeX version `\input \jobname.tex` and the LaTeX version `\input{\jobname.tex}`. Those then test whether the file exist at all and do all things that are not expandable. (Have you tried scanning the codes you get.) The TeX version of `\input` (in LaTeX `\@@input`) is even a primitive I believe.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel TeX's `\input` is a primitive, but doesn't it 'sort-of'-'I would never say this to egreg' *expand* (in the true macro sense) to the file contents?

Comment: I guess, yes and no. It does insert it in the input stream but then it would just continue to expand it when it is written on the PS/Barcode code. You need to `\detokenize` it before. But for some reason, it cannot find the file. I guess the `catchfile` will be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A start: Using the `catchfile` package to write the content of the file into a macro that will then get expanded once and detokenized for `\psbarcode`.

For some reason my scanner doesn’t show any `\`s, `\b`s or `\t`s. I don’t know whether this is a matter of `\psbarcode` or of my scanner that interprets them as some kind of [escape sequences](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_Character#Escape-Sequenzen_in_C_und_verwandten_Programmiersprachen) (German list). However, the sequence `\string\\` shows up correctly as `\`.

Also, an empty line shows up as `\par` (or rather `par`).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode,catchfile}
\CatchFileDef\myFile{\jobname.tex}{}
\makeatletter\let\TeXinput\@@input\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\meaning\myFile

\begin{pspicture}
  \expandafter\psbarcode\expandafter{\detokenize\expandafter{\myFile}\string\\}{}{qrcode}
  % fails with "I can't find file" error
%  \expandafter\psbarcode\expandafter
%    {\detokenize\expandafter{\TeXinput\jobname.tex}}{}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 8):

That will make no real sense! PostScript and TeX have different special characters. For example: a single `)` without a correscponding `(` in your TeX code will break the PostScript code. `)` is the closing character for a PostScript string; it has to be escaped by `\)`. But that has another meaning in TeX. Same for other characters.

You need a pre-processor which escapes the `)` character in the TeX file. However, if you do not have a single `)` in your TeX source you can use the optional argument `file` (needs latest TL2013):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode,fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\VerbatimInput{\jobname.tex}% test 

\begin{pspicture}(2in,2in)
  \psbarcode[file]{\jobname.tex}{}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]